# Cannot import Tkinter using Canopy

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I'm unsuccessfully trying to import Tk using [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/):

```
In [1]: import Tkinter
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a0c812564da3> in <module>()
----> 1 import Tkinter

/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py
in <module>()
     37     # Attempt to configure Tcl/Tk without requiring PATH
     38     import FixTk
---> 39 import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
     40 tkinter = _tkinter # b/w compat for export
     41 TclError = _tkinter.TclError

ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so,
2): Library not loaded:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/111.222.33344/lib/libtcl8.5.dylib
  Referenced from:
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so
  Reason: image not found
```

and:

```
$ ls -l /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 cassio  admin  66184 Mar 25 17:54
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so

$ ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/111.222.33344/lib/libtcl8.5.dylib
ls: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/111.222.33344/lib/libtcl8.5.dylib:
No such file or directory
```

I thought Tk/Tcl came pre-installed with python.
How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: `Tk import failed`. But when it didn't fail - nothing was shown and after a while Python kernel died.

I don't know how to fix it, but running from terminal helped (i'm using OS X 10.6.8). I've just typed (for file named test.py)

```
$python test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Jonathan March from Enthought responded to this issue by posting a [workaround](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23707811-TKinter-broken-on-Canopy-OS-X-) on the Enthought knowledge base website that involves changing some dynamic libraries and changing the default UI backend.